# antd form: how to display super long text in antd form

Tags: antd

I'm using antd form and one of the field's initial values might contain very long text. Is there a good way to deal with this situation? like ellipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can write ellipse = true in the column initialization

ex:

```
const column = [ {  title: 'xxx',  dataIndex: 'xxx',  ellipse: true,  key: 'xxx', } ]
```